# Find the count and position of a character- VB script

Tags: vbscript

How do i find count of a character in a string and its index value in VB script.
For example "Lion is king of jungle" in this example if n count is 3 and position 3,10 and 18.

Comment: Count with [For...next loop](http://ss64.com/vb/for.html) `for ii = 1 to Len(sMyString)` using `mid(sMyString,ii,1)` function...

Comment: @Arsh: Welcome to StackOverflow. You really need to show us the code you are having trouble with - this site is for solving coding and development problems, rather than just giving you the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RegExp - As in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim s : s     = "Lion is king of jungle"
Dim c : c     = "n"
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global  = True
r.Pattern = c
Dim ms : Set ms = r.Execute(s)
WScript.Echo "found", ms.Count, "tokens of", c
Dim m
For Each m In ms
    WScript.Echo m.FirstIndex + 1
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 29181557.vbs
found 3 tokens of n
4
11
19
```

The `+ 1` adjusts to VBScript's one based string indices.